# jsfiddle example works, won't run in my jsfiddle account editor

Tags: jsfiddle

This works fine

https://jsfiddle.net/blazeeboy/fNPvf/

I copied it precisely to my account & editor here, and it won't work. No action on pressing the "submit" button.

https://jsfiddle.net/user/digitareous/fiddles/

```
function change(){

var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
   }

  var title = document.getElementById('title');
   title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;

   }
```

I looked at jsfiddle "getting started" and "beginning tutorial" pages looked for other such starting points, and clicked all around in jsfiddle, run, update, etc.  I also built a fiddle from the tutorial and tried to run it, no joy.  Tried IE11, Chrome and Firefox. I could not get any of them make the jsfiddle run.

Something is making my jsfiddle editor "inactive".

What might that be?

Comment: I have tried both the linked jsfiddles and confirm the second jsfiddle doesnt work properly when the submit button is pressed. But I have no solution for you, sorry.  Note the 2nd jsfiddle does actually run because if you change the text "Javascript example no.2" the new value is correctly displayed when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second jsfiddle click on the javascript settings button (top right corner of the javascript code field of the editor) and in the popup field "LOAD TYPE" select "no wrap - in head".

You should now get the desired behavior.

(I get stuck on this from time to time - it is very frustrating).

Comment: @wayfarer...sorry I don't understand.